# Java Script return function() {}

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Можете подсказать в чём разница между return function в которой внутри тоже находится return со значением от function без return. Пример:

```
function makeCounter() {
  var currentCount = 1;
  return function() { 
    return currentCount++;
  };
}
function makeCounter() {
  var currentCount = 1;
  function() { 
    return currentCount++;
  };
}
```

Comment: одна функция возвращает значение, а другая нет

Comment: тем, что вторая вызовет ошибку, ибо не задано имя внутренней функции))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и это тоже :-)

Answer (score 0):

Вторая функция вызовет ошибку, так как она неправильно объявлена.

Разница в том что в первом случае вернется сама функция.

```
a = function makeCounter() {
  var currentCount = 1;
  return function() { // возвращается функция а не currentCount++;
    return currentCount++; 
  };
}
```

Если нужно получить результат второго return, воспользуйтесь самовызывающейся функцией.

```
function a (var1, var2, var3) {
  return (function (c, b, v) {
    return c+b+v; // возвращается функция, которая сразу же после 
                  // объявления выполняется, поэтому возвращается сумма.
  })(var1, var2, var3);
};
```